# CLI Screenshot; No X Server

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, screenshot, tty

How could I capture a screenshot of a Linux tty, CLI terminal session; without an X server (or similar)?

If an X server is connected, I will typically use `scrot`.
But in some situations it's unavailable, or impractical.

[image: Linux CLI]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [snapscreenshot](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/snapscreenshot.html)

```
snapscreenshot -c4 -x2 > shot.tga
```

[image]

Comment: Why have I never heard of this?!

Comment: This, or something like it, ought to come installed by default on.. pretty much every operating system ever. At the very least, it should be added to all major, default software repositories, package managers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know of any similar alternatives? It did the job; I'm just curious.